# react router v4 link onclick get link prop

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I am new using react router v4. I have a link that runs a function in the onClick event and then redirects to a specific route.

This is the link:

```
<Link className={''} 
    to={'/test'}
    onClick={this.testFunction}>To test</Link>
```

and the test function:

```
testFunction(event){
    e.preventDefault();
    // do some things...
    this.props.history.push('/test');
}
```

This works but I need to write both times the "/test" route (in the Link component and in the function).

Is there a way of getting the "to" prop so I don't have to write it twice?

Comment: Why do you need ``Link`` in this case? If you are doing the ``this.props.history.push()``, you can switch to a normal ``<a>`` tag or w/e tag that has ``onClick``

Comment: I've never tried this before but I assume you could use something like `event.target.to`

Comment: @Chimera.Zen I think if you use event.target.to you get the full path, but the router will work with relative paths

Comment: @HRK44 this is another good option, I didn't think of this, I thought I had to use only react-router components

Comment: @Chimera.Zen I tried using target and I also got the full path and my router brakes with it. I guess I could parse it, but seems easier to use a different solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use "withRouter" in your component:

```
import {Link, withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
...    
export default withRouter(TestComponent);
```

you can access the route's path by using:

```
this.props.match.path
```

Use this in your code:

```
testFunction(event){
    e.preventDefault();
    // do some things...
    this.props.history.push(this.props.match.path);
}
```

When you use "withRouter" in your component you can access the match, location and history props of the route.

[withRouter](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md) official documentation

[match](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/d28d46dce08a5756a085f7e5eebb5169ea59e40b/packages/react-router/docs/api/match.md)  official documentation

Hope it helps!

Comment: yes I am using withRouter but didn't try finding the info in match, thank you!